# how to use Trajan font in website with typekit?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I need to use a font named Trajan in a new website, is there anyway to use it safely without using Typekit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only two ways at this time to use Trajan Pro from Adobe legally on a website. One you have mentioned being Typekit and the other is WebINK web font service. Both companies have legal rights to offer you the font for use on your website via their services.

Answer (score 3):

The @font-face generator at Font Squirrel does a great job of generating code to include any font via CSS in a variety of methods so it's compatible with all major browsers.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: This page does not allow Trajan conversions.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest reading [this article](http://interactiveblend.com/blog/online/how-to-use-any-font-on-the-web/)? It describes several ways to use a non-standard font on your website. From my experience, it was pretty easy to use [Typeface](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free font kind of similar to Trajan Pro. It's called **Goudy Trajan** and was designed by [CastleType](http://castletype.com/). You can get free trial here: http://www.castletype.com/html/tipoteca/goudy-trajan-regular.html

The [license](http://www.castletype.com/html/misc/castletype-eula.html) states that it is allowed to use as a webfont.